# Protect script from bots and unwanted requests posting data

Tags: php, android, token

I'm modifying an Android app that utilizes a webapp via a webview.  Currently the the code base for the webapp is written in ColdFusion - so all the session management is done in CF.  There are certain hooks in the webapp that force the Android app to do native functions and sometimes call external scripts in PHP.

These php scripts get data posted to them (userid, friendid, etc) - currently the php scripts just make sure there is valid data being posted, then process the request if the data is present and valid.

I am looking for ways to increase the security of these php scripts to prevent bots / malicious users from posting false data to these pages - at this point nothings stopping anyone sending a correct userid/friendid and having the script from executing.

Session management would be the first line of defense, but since the webapp is in a different language I can't use that - and sometimes the php scripts are on a different domain completely (same server though).

The other method I considered was on sign up creating a user token to associate with a user, and saving this on the Android side of things - then when requesting these php scripts send the userid and token.  And verify the token for that user matches in the remote database - this would make it harder to guess posting credentials for malicious user.  Clearly not the best because the token is stored locally and going over the wire, but I digress.

Question are there any better methods to use in order to protect these lone php scripts from being executed, with out the use of session management?  Does my token idea make any sense?

Note: I can use SSL on any / all requests.

Comment: Is the goal to avoid a DOS attack, or to weed out bogus requests? If it's avoiding DOS, what limitations are there (should there be) in terms of maximum requests allowed in a given amount of time?  If it's avoiding bogus requests, what do you have in place already to distinguish "real" requests from bogus ones (login/password, whitelist, etc)?  Even with sessions in place, you still need some mechanism to determine the good guys from the bad guys or, in case of DOS, know how much is too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know exactly what you need, if you're up to the task. Your API needs to impliment OAuth2.0.

What OAuth can provide you is a secure way to pass information to and from your service while making sure that all secret information is kept private and that only the correct people can access that information. It gives each user a unique signature.

OAuth is used by Facebook, Google, Twitter and more to give developers a secure way to access information while keeping everyone from doing things they shouldn't be doing.

OAuth has support for ColdFusion, Java, PHP, C#, dotNet, VB.net, LIST, Javascript, Perl, Python, Ruby, and more.

http://oauth.net/

Comment: I have looked into OAuth before and am looking for an in-house solution at the moment.  Thanks for the idea Steven!

Comment: And I'm aware this is the "right" answer for most situations :)

Comment: This is the right answser if all the queries of your application are done by registered users. If your application can be used by guests, it's more complicated, and a signature-based solution is generally used.

Answer (score 4):

Session management or OAuth are the best solutions, but not the easiest. An easier way is implementing a hashing algorithm in both your app and the PHP scripts. When the app prepares a request, you hash some of the values that are being sent to the server using your secret method. This hash is being sent with the request. The server does the same and compares the two hashes. When they're the same, it knows the request is from the app (or someone who cracked your algorithm). When they're not, the server can simply ignore the request.

***An example:***

**Data:** userid = 2042; name = JohnDoe; email = john-doe@someprovider.com

**Hash** (in PHP, but you should implement it in the app as well):

```
<?php

$userid = 2042;
$name = 'JohnDoe'
$email = 'john-doe@someprovider.com';

// Remove some letters with other letters
$name = str_replace(array('a', 'd', 'g'), array('E', 'x', '9'), $name);

// Reverse a string
$email = strrev($email);

// Make a super secret hash (with salt!)
$hash = sha1('fnI87' . $useris . '87bk;s.' . $name . 'unf%gd' . $email);

// Some more fun
$hash = str_rot13($hash);

?>
```

**Request:** http://www.your-server.com/script.php?userid=2042&name=JohnDoe&email=john-doe@someprovider.com&hash=YOUR-GENERATED-HASH

Now the server can apply the same hashing method and compare the resulting hash with the hash sent with the request.

Comment: I like this approach, but unfortunately in the world of Android apps - I have to assume and some point it will get reverse-engineered and my hashing algorithm would be uncovered.  With this in mind I thought my token idea above would be safer, because then the attacker would only have the token of one user, as opposed to having the algorithm that could apply to every user.  Thoughts?

Comment: The idea is good but, to increase the security, you have to increase the entropy by adding a salt, and using hashing functions. In your example, force your $hash using reverse-enginering is relatively easy.

Comment: @Julien In my example the token would be 100+ random chars generated on the server side...are you saying that can be reversed easily?  I'm a little confused.

Comment: One can use user unique token combined with random session salt and hash that. However, any method that is based on shared secret (symmetric encryption) can be easily cracked by the end user. If you cannot trust your end user, do not allow them to talk to your server (via app or any other means). To make sure nobody else can talk to the end user client app, you need public key encryption, which unfortunately is not that easy to implement. In that case, the client app can verify that the message is really sent by your server. You still cannot trust that any message you receive is from your app.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest a more abstract approach, but similar to Jonathan's.

I make the following assumptions:

- You have a PHP-script that anyone can call (if they know the URL / sniff the network packets).
- Your android app is closed source; meaning that if you have a hash algorithm no-one but you will know what it is.
- You want to prevent anyone from directly calling the PHP scripts - circumventing the app and any security you might have built in there.

What you need is way to identify that *your* app is sending the requests, and not someone else.

The idea is that you generate a signature for each request that only *your* app can make (ie. a salt + a hash).

```
$input = array(
    "userid" => 1234,
    "friendid" => 2345
    "etc" => "..."
);

$salt = "s3kr4tsal7"; // this is essentially your app signature
$signature = md5($salt . serialize($input));  // you could also use json_encode or any other to-string serialization
                                              // pick whichever is easy to do in PHP and in your app

$request = array(
    "input" => $input,
    "signature" => $signature
); // send this
```

Then in your PHP script check if the signature matches the calculated signature. This is similar to Jonathan's solution but it allows for any input, it's not dependent on `$email` or any other property. I also don't think you need an overly complex hashing algorithm, just `md5` with a salt is 'hard enough'.

There is another type of attack you should be aware of and that is a replay-attack.

If you look at the *RAW* data going over the line, you could capture it and simply play it again. If you know what action has what output you can simply repeat the output.

The typical solution for a replay-attack is a trial-and-response. SSL does this for you but you could also make a custom implementation (but that is significantly more complex).

Comment: Hoi Frits! My snippet was just an example; when applied in a real script it should work with all forms of input. Don't you think a single salt is too easy to crack if someone really wants to? By adding some more obfuscation (with functions like `str_replace`, `strrev` or `str_rot13`) it's much harder to reverse engineer the hashing method.

Comment: The very nature of a hashing method is that it is hard to reverse, it doesn't make sense to add more steps. `strrev` does nothing to increase the entropy, `str_replace` actually decreases entropy. `rot13` rotates the character set so it might increase entropy but not significantly. Adding a salt however adds _more_ information to the input which _does_ increase entropy.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, it depends on what level of protection you need, and how much you are willing to invest. Since you cannot use sessions, you need some sort of a stateless way to authenticate. There are generally two ways to do this: post credentials each time (e.g., basic authentication) or send some sort of a token (BTW, the session ID is exactly that, a token that links to a live session on the server).

When you generate the token, it is a good idea to use a standard and proven algorithm, instead of inventing your own and/or relying on obscurity. Even if it looks mostly secure, it might not be. For example, there are known attacks against the MD5 idea above (it is easy to append data to the message without knowing the key and obtain another valid MAC).  [HMAC-SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC-SHA1) is designed to avoid those.

First thing first: if you can, *do* use SSL for all requests. This would accomplish a few things at the same time:

- users (your app) can be sure that they are posting their data to the right place (i.e., your webapp). SSL server authentication takes care of this.
- it would make sure any crednetials/tokens you post are automatically encrypted.
- replay attack become practically impossible

It seems you already have authenticated users, so issuing tokens should be relatively easy. You might want to think about the protocol to implement, but as you consider more cases, you will be getting closer to re-inventing OAuth and friends. Some things to consider:

- an expiration period on tokens: so that even if someone gets a hold of one, they cannot use it indefinitely.
- a way to revoke tokens
- maybe have different tokens for different parts (services) of the webapp, so you can grant/revoke access to only the necessary services

To make sure you (i.e., your webapp(s)) are the only one that can issue said tokens you would want to sign them with a key only you have. Since the signer and verifier are the same (you) you don't have to use public key cryptography, HMAC should do. You could, for example, concatenate the username, issue time and any other relevant information, and use them as input to HMAC. Pack those parameters along with the signature (HMAC output) to create a token, and have the app send it with each request. Verify on the server and allow access if valid, require re-login (new token) if expired, deny access otherwise.

Alternatively, if you want to authenticate just the app, and not get user info mixed up in this, you could use a similar approach to sign requests on the client (app side). If you choose this way, do use a standard algorithm. This would, of course, require the signing key (in some form) to be in the app, so if someone gets hold of it (by reverse engineering, etc.) they could issue as many requests as they want. There are ways to mitigate this though:

- implement the signing logic in native code
- don't store the raw key, but derive it at runtime from bits and pieces stored in different places

And of course, the easiest way of all would be to require basic or digest authentication at the server (over SSL, of course), and embed the username and password in the app (sufficiently obfuscated). On the server side that would require only a change in server configuration, a few lines added on the client side. The downside is that there is really no way to change those credentials if they get compromised (short of releasing a new version and blocking access from the old one to force people to update; not pretty).

Comment: Based on your 5th paragraph - would something like this suffice: $token = sha1($timestamp . $userid . $salt); ??  And by salt I would just have a random static string of chars..

Comment: Or is the php hash_hmac() better than sha1()?

Comment: Salt is probably the wrong term here. Salt is by definition not secret, and its purpose is to make sure that you get different output (password, key, etc.) even if the input is the same. Otherwise, you could figure out that the input was the same just by looking at the hash. You want to keep part of the input secret, so its actually a key. You could use `hash_hmac()` to implement HMAC-SHA1 and that should work for you. See example here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

Comment: **Never trust the client software.** It does not matter if the app is running the signing logic in native code or if the shared secret is computed runtime. **Always assume that attacker has all the knowledge that the app has.** Public key encryption does not help there, either. Public key encryption can verify that the message your server sends to the app is authentic but it cannot verify that the message you receive is generated by your application (instead of by attacker pretending to be the application).

Comment: @Mikko Your point being? You need to authenticate the app, so the app needs to have some sort of key or token. You can do your best to protect it and/or make it temporary, but that's it.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov: my point was that original question asked for a method for preventing malicious users from posting false data and I'm trying to tell that there's no way to identify a malicious user from a "normal" user. No amount of hashing or encryption can make anything sent by the client trustworthy because the client software may have been modified. To fix that, you'd need a DRM system which by definition cannot exists.